# How to read multiple tabs from excel sheet and convert to each Dataframe in java spark

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I am new to Spark 2.3 with java 1.8. I have to read one excel file and it will contain multiple tabs and each tab will have header and data.I would like to write a code to convert seperate dataframe for each tab from excel sheet. Please help me to write a code in Java 1.8 and Spark 2.3 (Not scala and Python)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do that (For multiple EXCEL files that I take as an input form google.sheets) :

1. Python Script to export all worksheets of a Workbook to CSV files
   (Using  beautifulsoup4 and Pandas libraries).
2. Shell Script to move the CSV files to HDFS (I have Spark deployed in
   Hortonworks)
3. Spark to map over all paths containing the CSV files (I listed them
   automatically using a function taking root directory of Files) then
   I load the CSV files (located on HDFS) using SparkSession. Finally
   you would have every Worksheet as a DataFrame.

**Function to List Files in a specific HDFS directory**

```
 def getListOfFilesInHDFS(str : String): Array[String] = {
    val fsPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(str)
    val status = hdfs.listStatus(fsPath)
    status.filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath.toString) ++
      status.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(dir => getListOfFilesInHDFS(dir.getPath.toString))
  }
```

**Function to load a single file from HDFS as a Dataframe:**

```
  def loadFileFromHDFS(path: String, format: String, header_boolean: Boolean, delimiter: String) = {
    DataCore.spark.read.format(format)
      .option("header", header_boolean)
      .option("delimiter", delimiter)
      .load(path)
  }
```

**Python Script to export Worksheets components of an EXCEL file :**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import unicodedata
import unidecode

encoding = "utf-8"

mkt_gdrive_file_src = '/path/to/file.xlsx' # file Source
mkt_gdrive_file_csv = '/path/to/file.csv' # file Destination


dfMkt = pd.read_excel(mkt_gdrive_file_src, sheet_name='Sheet1')
dfMkt.columns = ['column1', 'column2','column3', 'column4', 'column5']

def safe_str(s):
    try:
        return str(s)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return unidecode.unidecode(s)

def keep_safe_str(obj):
    try:
        return str(obj)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return obj.encode('UTF-16').decode('UTF-16') 

def cleanDf(df):
     # cleaning not enabled for now
    cols = df.dtypes[df.dtypes == 'object'].index.values
    for c in cols:
        df[c] = df[c].fillna('').map(safe_str)
    return df



cleanDf(dfMkt).to_csv(mkt_gdrive_file_csv, index=None, sep='|', header=None, encoding='utf-8')
```

**Spark function to map over files list then load them as a Dataframe :**

```
    val crc_hdfs_paths = "/your/root/directory/to/csv/files/" //in HDFS

    def loadDataframesFromCSVFilesRoot(crc_hdfs_paths_string : String) = {
        getListOfFilesInHDFS(crc_hdfs_paths_string)
          .map(hdfs_file_path => {
            loadFileFromHDFS(hdfs_file_path, "csv", true, ";")
    }
```

Then you can automate all this.

Good luck :)